# While reading sql.Rows.Next() performing another query returns error: 1046 no database selected

Tags: mysql, go

(errcheck and some details omitted)

### Setup

I opened the database like this:

```
d, err = sql.Open("mysql", "user:passwd@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/")
_, err = d.Exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myblog")
_, err = d.Exec("USE myblog")
```

But if I change it to this, everything is fine:

```
d, err = sql.Open("mysql", "user:passwd@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/myblog")
```

### Execution

I have two tables:

```
articles
ID, ArticleID, Title, CreateDate, PreviewContent, Content, PRIMARY KEY (ID)

categories
ArticleID, CategoryName, PRIMARY KEY (ArticleID, CategoryName)
```

In one function, I select 10 rows from `articles`:

```
selectAtcs := `
    SELECT ArticleID, Title, CreateDate, PreviewContent
    FROM articles 
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    LIMIT ?
    OFFSET ?`

var rows *sql.Rows
rows, err = db.DB.Query(selectAtcs, 10, 0)
```

While reading each one of them, I performed another query to get the category related to `ArticleID`:

```
for rows.Next() {
    var a Article
    err = rows.Scan(&a.ArticleID, &a.Title, &a.CreateDate, &a.PreviewContent)

    selectCtg := `
        SELECT CategoryName
        FROM categories 
        WHERE ArticleID = ?`

    var ctgRows *sql.Rows
    ctgRows, err = db.DB.Query(selectCtg, a.ArticleID)
}
```

The last line in the above code returns an error: `1046 no database selected`

Answer (score 6):

sql.DB is not a single connection to the database but a pool of connections, therefore there is no guarantee that the same connection will be used in subsequent queries (unless you do them within a transaction).

From [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB):

> DB is a database handle representing a pool of zero or more underlying
>   connections. It's safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.
>
> The sql package creates and frees connections automatically; it also
>   maintains a free pool of idle connections. If the database has >a
>   concept of per-connection state, such state can only be reliably
>   observed within a transaction

Another word of warning - a connection on which you run queries that change the state of the connection (eg. running directly SQL statements such as `USE <db_name>`, `BEGIN`, etc.) will return to the pool of connections used to connect to the DB, and this state may corrupt other queries (where you expect the state to be clean).